# How can I get ChatGPT to write with more varied paragraph lengths?

Tags: chatgpt

I've noticed that when ChatGPT writes multiple paragraphs, the paragraphs have consistent lengths of roughly 200 characters. Often more than 100, and less than 400. I'm not sure if this is just a result of of the specific prompts that have been feeding the responses (I've been hunting ChatGPT answers on Stack Overflow).

How can I get ChatGPT or encourage it to write with more varied, or shorter or longer paragraph lengths?

Answer (score 2):

You can get ChatGPT to output different lengths of text by telling it to use different word lengths. Tell ChatGPT the number of paragraphs also. The output may not be the exact length entered, but it generates something long or short depending on the input.

I have a Python script that I use for ChatGPT. The following are examples on how to have ChatGPT change the word length of every paragraph:

### Short length output

Describe a stable environment. Make it four paragraphs long. Each paragraph must be 30 words.

> assistant: A stable environment is characterized by consistent and predictable factors that promote feelings of safety and security. In a stable environment, the physical conditions remain steady without abrupt changes or dangers. This includes having a reliable source of food, clean water, and comfortable shelter.

> Furthermore, a stable environment also encompasses emotional stability, where individuals feel supported and nurtured. It is a place where relationships are built upon trust, respect, and open communication. Within this context, individuals have a sense of belonging and know they can rely on others for emotional support.

> In a stable environment, there is a sense of routine and structure. This provides a sense of predictability and familiarity, reducing stress and creating feelings of comfort. Having a stable routine allows individuals to plan their activities and have a clear understanding of what to expect.

> Lastly, a stable environment also promotes mental and psychological well-being. It includes access to healthcare services, educational opportunities, and resources that promote personal growth and self-improvement. Overall, a stable environment creates a foundation for individuals to thrive and reach their full potential, ensuring their overall well-being.

### Long length output

Describe a stable environment. Make it two paragraphs long. Each paragraph must be 70 words long.

> assistant: A stable environment is one where there is a sense of balance, security, and predictability. It is a place where there is little to no risk of sudden and drastic changes or upheavals. In a stable environment, there is a consistent and reliable support system, whether it be in the form of family, friends, or community. This helps individuals feel grounded and confident in their surroundings, enabling them to pursue personal growth and achieve their goals.

> Moreover, a stable environment fosters a sense of peace and tranquility. It provides a space where individuals can maintain a routine, plan for the future, and make decisions with a clear mind. In such an environment, there is harmony and order, allowing people to focus on their well-being and cultivate healthy relationships. A stable environment also provides the necessary conditions for emotional and mental well-being, offering stability and serenity in an ever-changing world.